# How do I enable subfolders in Dovecot?

Tags: linux, email, imap, vps, dovecot

In the past I was able to drag and drop my folder with subfolders (local emails) into my imap accounts inside Thunderbird. Now I moved to my own vps and its running Dovecot. So far so good with emails. Today I wanted to copy some folders with messages again but I realized that it does not let me copy to folders. I can drag and drop individual emails into some folders in Imap however folders stuff does not work.

I am not sure what this feature is called. The previous email servers might be using some other imap server so I am really not sure what it might be even called.

Is this a Dovecot or Thundenbird thing? If it is a Dovecot feature how I enable it on my server?

Dovecot is running on Debian Wheezy 64 bit vps

thanks

Comment: Can you create new, empty folders? Are you creating the folders at the root of your mailbox or inside some other folder (like your inbox)?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I already have folders in there (created by thunderbird). I can create folders individually in TB but where things do not work is when I try to drag and drop folders with subfolders and messages in them (local to Imap server). This kind of thing worked pretty well for me when I was using paid email servers. Maybe they werenot using Dovecot, I just want to know if it is possible with my imap server.

Comment: Is this related to [Sub-folders in Dovecot](https://superuser.com/q/813362/218574 "Sub-folders in Dovecot?")? The [link](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/Maildir "Maildir configuration") mentioned in the answer explains a thing or two about mail folders.