# Sub-folders in Dovecot?

Tags: imap, dovecot, gmail-imap

How can I enable my Dovecot IMAP server to support sub-folders?

When I am trying to do an imapsync from my Gmail account to my Dovecot IMAP server I keep getting the following error:

```
NO [CANNOT] Mailbox doesn't allow inferior mailboxes
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer for this:

I had to change a small configuration in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf (on Ubuntu Server 14.04)

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir:LAYOUT=fs
```

Source: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/Maildir

Comment: This works if you are using the `maildir` format. If you need the `mbox` format, check this instead: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/mbox/mboxchildfolders/?highlight=mbox%20configuration